# Connect service to existing meteor account

Tags: javascript, oauth, meteor, account

I am setting up a meteor app that involves signing up with a username and password, then hopefully connecting that account with facebook and twitter.

I have the first part up and running easily, just with the accounts package. But when I have a logged in user call Meteor.loginWithFacebook(), it logs them out and creates a new account. What I want is something that adds the facebook credentials to the currently logged in user.

The meteor docs have this:

```
{
  _id: "bbca5d6a-2156-41c4-89da-0329e8c99a4f",  // Meteor.userId()
  username: "cool_kid_13", // unique name
  emails: [
    // each email address can only belong to one user.
    { address: "cool@example.com", verified: true },
    { address: "another@different.com", verified: false }
  ],
  createdAt: Wed Aug 21 2013 15:16:52 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  profile: {
    // The profile is writable by the user by default.
    name: "Joe Schmoe"
  },
  services: {
    facebook: {
      id: "709050", // facebook id
      accessToken: "AAACCgdX7G2...AbV9AZDZD"
    },
    resume: {
      loginTokens: [
        { token: "97e8c205-c7e4-47c9-9bea-8e2ccc0694cd",
          when: 1349761684048 }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which appears to be an account with a username that's also authenticated with Facebook. But I'm not sure if that's just an example that you can't actually achieve with basic Meteor stuff.

What I am trying to make is basically

```
Meteor.connectWithExternalAccount();
```

which runs the same process as Meteor.loginWithExternalAccount(), but just adds the information to the currently logged in user.

If someone could just explain the accounts-base package a bit so I could know where to start for myself that would be great.

Also, does anyone know if this will be included in any future versions of Meteor?

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1133

Comment: emgee, that looks like what I'm looking for! Problem is, my 'accounts-base' folder doesn't have an accounts_client.js file. At least not where I'm looking, which is in the project file .meteor/local/build/app/packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there's been work to solve this problem, but unfortunately the pull request https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1133 never got merged. Probably your best bet is check the meteor-core Google Groups and see if there was any comment on it and if not, see if you can get a core dev to comment on it.

If you want to still use the pull request, what you could do is remove the various Meteor `accounts-*` packages, then in the root of your project, create a `/packages` folder and copy yubozhao's patched `accounts-*` packages in there (probably smart to append `-custom`). You'd then `meteor add accounts-base-custom`, etc. to add them to your project.

Note though, yubozhao wrote this is 6-7 months ago and you may need to stick with whatever version of Meteor that was current then for it to work.

*Update April 2014:*
There's an Atmosphere package now that has a similar use case that might be useful: https://atmospherejs.com/package/accounts-merge

Comment: I will try cloning the files from the pull request into a package, and just hope that works. If it doesn't, I guess I'll just try to read through it and find what has broken in the last six months. I couldn't find any discussion of it in the meteor google group.

Comment: I couldn't get this technique to work at all. Any other ideas?

Comment: The current version of Meteor as of the time the pull request was originally written was 0.6.4 — might try `meteor run --release 0.6.4` and see if you can get it to work in that version.

Comment: I did try that. I think the problem came from having two packages writing about the Accounts object or something. Couldn't even get Meteor.linkWithFacebook to exist on the client.

Comment: Did you remove the stock Meteor Accounts packages? And only use yubozhao's patched packages? Just as a point, I've never actually tried the patched ones so don't know if they work or not.

Comment: That appears to break some more things.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a code that worked for me ( inside server folder ):

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    var email, oldUser, service;
    /*
    user.groups = {
        created: "",
        invited:"",
        RSVP:{
            coming:"",
            notComing:"",
            noReplay:""
        }
    };
    */
    if (user.profile == null) {
        user.profile = options.profile
    }
    if (user.services != null) {
        service = _.keys(user.services)[0];
        email = user.services[service].email;
        if (email != null) {
            oldUser = Meteor.users.findOne({
                "emails.address": email
            });
            if (oldUser != null) {
                if (oldUser.services == null) {
                    oldUser.services = {};
                }
                if (service === "google" || service === "facebook") {
                    oldUser.services[service] = user.services[service];
                    Meteor.users.remove(oldUser._id);
                    user = oldUser;
                }
            } else {
                if (service === "google" || service === "facebook") {
                    if (user.services[service].email != null) {
                        user.emails = [
                            {
                                address: user.services[service].email,
                                verified: true
                            }
                        ];
                    } else {
                        throw new Meteor.Error(500, "" + service + " account has no email attached");
                    }
                    user.profile.name = user.services[service].name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return user;
});

userAddOauthCredentials: function(token, userId, service) {
        var data, oldUser, selector, updateSelector;
        switch (service) {
            case "facebook":
                data = Facebook.retrieveCredential(token).serviceData;
                break;
            case "google":
                data = Google.retrieveCredential(token).serviceData;
        }
        selector = "services." + service + ".id";
        oldUser = Meteor.users.findOne({
            selector: data.id
        });
        if (oldUser != null) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(500, ("This " + service + " account has already") + "been assigned to another user.");
        }
        updateSelector = "services." + service;
        Meteor.users.update(userId, {
            $set: {
                updateSelector: data
            }
        });
        if (!_.contains(Meteor.user().emails, data.email)) {
            return Meteor.users.update(userId, {
                $push: {
                    "emails": {
                        address: data.email,
                        verified: true
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

inside client js folder :

```
var addUserService;

addUserService = function(service) {
    if (service === "email") {
} else {
    switch (service) {
        case "facebook":
            return Facebook.requestCredential({
                requestPermissions: ["email", "user_friends", "manage_notifications"]
            }, function(token) {
                return Meteor.call("userAddOauthCredentials", token, Meteor.userId(), service, function(err, resp) {
                    if (err != null) {
                        return Meteor.userError.throwError(err.reason);
                    }
                });
            });
        case "google":
            return Google.requestCredential({
                requestPermissions: ["email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"],
                requestOfflineToken: true
            }, function(token) {
                return Meteor.call("userAddOauthCredentials", token, Meteor.userId(), service, function(err, resp) {
                    if (err != null) {
                        return Meteor.userError.throwError(err.reason);
                    }
                });
            });
    }
}
```

};

same js file inside template events:

```
"click a": function(e) {
       var service;
        e.preventDefault();
        service = $(event.target).data("service");
        return addUserService(service);
    }
```

and for the html just done this:

```
<div class="social"><a id="fb" data-service="facebook"><img src="/../facebook.png"></a></div>
    <div class="social"><a id="go" data-service="google"><img src="/../googleplus.png"></a></div>
```

mainly you need to have the data-service set to your service, then the template click event takes the data-service and execute the addUserService(data-passed).

hope it will work, please let me know.

Comment: This relies on getting a users email on signup, correct? And it doesn't work with twitter, because you can't get a twitter users email through the api. This doesn't fit my use case, as I don't ask for email on signup and twitter is very important.

Comment: yes it rilies on getting the email from the user, i dont know about twitter , but it seems right to act based on email address obviously because its uniqe.

Comment: I'm hoping for an answer that just uses the fact that the user is already logged into an account choose which account to add to.

Comment: I dont fully understand.  Your looking to add more accounts services to a user that is already looged in? If that is the case it can be easily done with checking Meteor.userid () and push the data to his user-> profile->services

Comment: I need the data that is created with Meteor.loginWithFacebook() though, and I can't get that without losing the userId