# Meteor Accounts via external services dont set user.username

Tags: meteor

I'm a complete newbie, and I've been fiddling with the Meteor 1.0 sample todo list app to connect google oauth to it.

When I do so the page no longer renders properly because **{{username}}** is not set at all.

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users says "username: a unique String identifying the user." but the oauth stuff doesn't create one for you.

[Connect service to existing meteor account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391689/connect-service-to-existing-meteor-account) talks about linking an already existing account to another service, but in this case I just want to use the external service.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182903/meteor-facebook-registration uses onCreateUser() to manually set

```
user.username = user.services.facebook.name
```

but this isn't portable across services nor to guarantee uniqueness.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2 defines the User schema so that **username** is mandatory.

When I dump the users table (some fields removed) the google account doesn't have a username, and there is no field that can really take on that value automatically as there could be a clash. Email could be used but I'd rather the username wasn't the email address. Do I just force the user to specify a desired username?

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.users.find()
{
    "_id" : "YNWt2cATMsKFG7od6",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-11-05T11:08:00.406Z"),
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
        },
    },
    "username" : “a_user”
}
{
    "_id" : "CyQsJqcez3kWTRHyQ",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-11-05T12:09:40.139Z"),
    "profile" : {
        "name" : “Alice User”
    },
    "services" : {
        "google" : {
            "email" : “a_user@example.com",
            "family_name" : “User”,
            "gender" : “female",
            "given_name" : "Alice”,
            "id" : "1115",
            "name" : “Alice User,
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my application, I am using this to handle the same problem.

```
username = user.services.facebook.name
user.username=generateUsername(username)

generateUsername = function(username) {
  var count;
  username = username.toLowerCase().trim().replace(" ", "");
  count = Meteor.users.find({"profile.un": username}).count();
  if (count === 0) {
    return username;
  } 
  else {
    return username + (count + 1)
}
```

This is will create a unique username. After successful signup you can allow the users to change the username and check your db for its existence.

Comment: I like the idea of changing the username. I hadn't thought of that. I just assumed it to be set once, but that's what the id field is for.

Comment: Really handy thank you. the last `.toString()` call is unnecessary though. Javascript will turn the number to a string automatically.

Comment: Updated the snippet based on your suggestion @SStanley.

Comment: How is this ensuring uniqueness of the username ? username + (count + 1) could be an existing username, no?

Comment: Thanks, just what I need, but where exactly are you placing this code?

Comment: i have added it in my server method please refer https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#oauth-calling-api

Comment: this code works only one time?
username , unsername1 and search username => username1 exist...
else return generateUsername(username + (count + 1)) should be better..

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it myself with facebook and google

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    if (options && options.profile) {
        user.profile = options.profile;

    }

    if (user.services) {

        var service = _.pairs(user.services)[0];

        var serviceName = service[0];
        var serviceData = service[1];

        console.log("serviceName", serviceName)

        if (serviceName == "facebook") {
            user.emails = [
                {"address": serviceData.email, "verified": true}
            ];
            user.profile = {"first_name": serviceData.first_name, "last_name": serviceData.last_name, "avatar": getFbPicture(serviceData.id)};
        }
        else if (serviceName == "google") {
            user.emails = [
                {"address": serviceData.email, "verified": true}
            ];
            user.profile = {"first_name": serviceData.given_name, "last_name": serviceData.family_name, "avatar": getGooglePicture(serviceData.id)};
        }

    }
    console.log("user created :", user)
    return user;
});
```

I do not use `username` but I use email so that I'm sure that it will be unique. After that 
I could allow the user to set his `username` or `display name` like Stackoverflow or other services do.

However you could use the **email** as `username` and again let the user change it later.

Comment: The trouble with this is what happens if another user with the same email address already exists? This could cause two user records with the same email address. The Meteor Docs recommend using Accounts.addEmail, however since the account isn't created yet in the onCreateUser hook, the call to Accounts.addEmail fails. https://github.com/splendido/meteor-accounts-emails-field/ might be a better solution.

Comment: If you try to create 2 accounts with the same email, it should fail. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1282 throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I use

```
if(user.services.facebook)
   this.user = user.services.facebook.name
if(user.services.google)
   this.user = user.services.google.name
```

Comment: Is this in the onCreateUser() method?
user looks like it would be the user context not just the username, as in https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser user.username

Comment: My bad, I was writing quickly, I meant user.username